# Can't modify an array within a loop (C)

Tags: c, arrays, string, function

I am currently developing a small program requires a function to return a string (character array), and two parameters which are (phrase, c). The 'phrase' is a string input and 'c' is the character which will be removed from the phrase. The left-over spaces will also be removed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//This method has two parameters: (str, c)
//It will remove all occurences of var 'c'
//inside of 'str'
char * rmchr(char * str, char *c) {
    //Declare result array
    char *strVal = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(str));

    //Iterate through each character
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
            *(strVal+i) = str[i];
        //Check if char matches 'c'
        if (strVal[i] != *c){
            //Assign filtered value to new array
            *(strVal+i) = str[i];
            printf("%c", strVal[i]);
        }
    }
    return strVal;
}

int main()
{
    char * result = rmchr("This is a great message to test with! It includes a lot of examples!","i");
    return 1;
}
```

Inside of the 'rmchr' function (if-statement), the array prints out exactly how I'd like to return it:

```
Ths s a great message to test wth! It ncludes a lot of examples!
```

The problem is that my return variable, 'strVal' isn't being modified outside of the if-statement. How can I modify the array permanently so my ideal output will be returned inside of 'result' (inside of main).

Comment: The first line inside your loop copies the character unconditionally

Comment: Hi there, thanks for pointing that out! I removed that line of code and replace the if statement with if(str[i] != *c). I tested the output and doesnt seem to modify the strVal values still.

Comment: You have to maintain two indices for modifying `strVal` and reading from `str`, since the index `i` is too far ahead in `strVal` after characters were skipped

Comment: Hi. Welcome to the community. C is very unsafe to learn without some kind of reputable guide, as there are subtle nuances which aren't well defined, fundamental concepts you appear to be missing. Which book are you reading?

Comment: What do you mean by "the left-over spaces will also be removed"?  Do you mean that there will be no character appearing in the string for each one that's deleted, or is there some heuristic such as "if the character to be deleted has one or more spaces before it and one or more spaces after it, then only a single space should appear in the output"?  I hope it is just the first, for your sake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few points to address. Primarily, this code directly copies the input string verbatim as it stands. The same `*(strVal+i) = str[i];` assignment takes place in two locations in the code which disregards the comparison against `*c`. Without some secondary index variable `j`, it becomes difficult to keep track of the end of the receiving string.

Additional notes:

- There is no `free` for your `malloc`; this creates a memory leak.
- You return exit code `1` which indicates abnormal program termination. `return 0` to indicate a normal exit.
- Don't cast the pointer `malloc` returns; this can hide errors.
- Validate `malloc` success and exit if it failed.
- `strlen()` is a linear time operation that iterates through the entire parameter string on each call. Call it once and store the result in a variable to save cycles.
- This code does not handle removal of extra spaces as required.

See the below sample for a possible implementation that addresses some of the above points:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *rmchr(char *str, char *c) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int len = strlen(str);
    char *result = malloc(sizeof(*result) * (len + 1));

    if (result == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (i < len) {
        if (str[i] != *c) {
            result[j++] = str[i++];
        }
        else {
            for (i++; i < len && str[i] == ' '; i++);
        }
    }

    result[j] = '\0';
    return result;
}

int main() {
    char *result = rmchr("This is a great message to test with! It includes a lot of examples!", "i");

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(result); i++) {
        printf("%c", result[i]);
    }

    free(result);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Ths s a great message to test wth! It ncludes a lot of examples!
```

Comment: I really appreciate the help, that makes it much more clear! That is a fantastic answer which only leaves me to one more question. What resources would you recommend to improve my C development skills?

Comment: No problem. Try the [K&R book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language).

Comment: Please note that this code also removes the spaces after any occurence of the `*c` character (e.g. `"a bc i    e"` -> `a bc e`), which may not be OP's expected behavior.

Comment: @Bob__ Good point; remove `else` block to taste. I may have misinterpreted "The left-over spaces will also be removed".